# How to select documents with values above the average

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a students collection with documents having following structure:

```
{
  "student_name": "john",
  "score": 39,
}
```

I want to select students who have a score greater than the average score of all the students.

I have tried following, but it only returns one student.

```
db.students.find().sort({"score":-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

I want to get the whole set of students if more than one student has the maximum score.

Comment: It would be helpful for us to see what you have tried, and what approach you have taken. This helps us give you the most insight into the solution, and that way if this ends up being a homework assignment then we still tricked you into learning something.

Comment: your query will fetch only one record and that will be the top scorer, since you have used sort score - descending order and limit as 1 record

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the highest value of a field for each group and the array of corresponding documents' field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007949/how-to-get-the-highest-value-of-a-field-for-each-group-and-the-array-of-correspo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method and the [`$avg`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) accumulator operator.

```js
var average = db.students.aggregate([
    { "$group": { "_id": "null", avg: { "$avg": "$score"} }}
]).toArray()[0]["avg"];
```

Then use the `.find()` method

```js
db.students.find({ "score": { "$gt": average } })
```