# How to get the maximum value of a field for each group with the array of corresponding documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5738cb363bb56eb8f76c2ba8"),
    "records" : [
        {
            "Name" : "Joe",
            "Salary" : 70000,
            "Department" : "IT"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5738cb363bb56eb8f76c2ba9"),
    "records" : [
        {
            "Name" : "Henry",
            "Salary" : 80000,
            "Department" : "Sales"
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Jake",
            "Salary" : 40000,
            "Department" : "Sales"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5738cb363bb56eb8f76c2baa"),
    "records" : [
        {
            "Name" : "Sam",
            "Salary" : 90000,
            "Department" : "IT"
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Tom",
            "Salary" : 50000,
            "Department" : "Sales"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to have the results with the highest salary by each department

```js
{"Name": "Sam", "Salary": 90000, "Department": "IT"}
{"Name": "Henry", "Salary": 80000, "Department": "Sales"}
```

I could get the highest salary. But I could not get the corresponding employee names.

```js
db.HR.aggregate([

    { "$unwind": "$records" },
    { "$group": 
        {
            "_id": "$records.Department",
            "max_salary": { "$max": "$records.Salary" }
        }
    }   
])
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: great question, Can you add what you have tried and got an error?

Comment: I could solve it in SQL with a self-join. But I can't find a way with Mongo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) your document after [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. You can also use the [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator in which case you will need to sort your documents in ascending order

```js
db.HR.aggregate([
    { '$unwind': '$records' }, 
    { '$sort': { 'records.Salary': -1 } }, 
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$records.Department', 
        'Name': { '$first': '$records.Name' } , 
        'Salary': { '$first': '$records.Salary' }
    }}
])
```

which produces:

```js
{ "_id" : "Sales", "Name" : "Henry", "Salary" : 80000 }
{ "_id" : "IT", "Name" : "Sam", "Salary" : 90000 }
```

---

To return the maximum salary and employees list for each department you need to use the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) in your group stage to return the maximum "Salary" for each group then use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator operator to return a list of "Name" and "Salary" for all employees for each group. From there you need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator in your [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to return a list of names alongside the maximum salary. Of course the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) here is used to compare each employee salary to the maximum value. The [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) does his work which is filter out all `false` and is fine as long as the data being filtered is "unique". In this case it "should" be fine, but if any two results contained the same "name" then it would skew results by considering the two to be one.

```js
db.HR.aggregate([
    { '$unwind': '$records' },
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$records.Department', 
        'maxSalary': { '$max': '$records.Salary' }, 
        'persons': { 
            '$push': {
                'Name': '$records.Name', 
                'Salary': '$records.Salary' 
            }
        }
    }}, 
    { '$project': { 
        'maxSalary': 1, 
        'persons': { 
            '$setDifference': [
                { '$map': {
                    'input': '$persons', 
                    'as': 'person', 
                    'in': {
                        '$cond': [
                            { '$eq': [ '$$person.Salary', '$maxSalary' ] }, 
                            '$$person.Name', 
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }}, 
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : "Sales", "maxSalary" : 80000, "persons" : [ "Henry" ] }
{ "_id" : "IT", "maxSalary" : 90000, "persons" : [ "Sam" ] }
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not the most intuitive thing, but instead of `$max` you should be using `$sort` and `$first`:

```
{ "$unwind": "$records" },
{ "$sort": { "$records.Salary": -1},
{ "$group" : 
    {
        "_id": "$records.Department",
        "max_salary": { "$first": "$records.Salary" },
        "name": {$first: "$records.Name"}
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I think this is doable using the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) operator (fair warning: I've not actually tried this) -

```
{ "$unwind": "$records" },
{ "$group": 
        {
            "_id": "$records.Department",
            "max_salary": { "$max": "$records.Salary" }
            "name" : "$$ROOT.records.Name"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```js
db.HR.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$records"},
    {"$group":{
        "_id": "$records.Department",
        "arr": {"$push": {"Name":"$records.Name", "Salary":"$records.Salary"}},
        "maxSalary": {"$max":"$records.Salary"}
    }},
    {"$unwind": "$arr"},
    {"$project": {
        "_id":1,
        "arr":1,
        "isMax":{"$eq":["$arr.Salary", "$maxSalary"]}
    }},
    {"$match":{
        "isMax":true
    }}
])
```

This solution takes advantage of the [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) operator to compare two fields in the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

Test case:

```js
db.HR.insert({"records": [{"Name": "Joe", "Salary": 70000, "Department": "IT"}]})
db.HR.insert({"records": [{"Name": "Henry", "Salary": 80000, "Department": "Sales"}, {"Name": "Jake", "Salary": 40000, "Department": "Sales"}, {"Name": "Santa", "Salary": 90000, "Department": "IT"}]})
db.HR.insert({"records": [{"Name": "Sam", "Salary": 90000, "Department": "IT"}, {"Name": "Tom", "Salary": 50000, "Department": "Sales"}]})
```

Result:

```js
{ "_id" : "Sales", "arr" : { "Name" : "Henry", "Salary" : 80000 }, "isMax" : true }
{ "_id" : "IT", "arr" : { "Name" : "Santa", "Salary" : 90000 }, "isMax" : true }
{ "_id" : "IT", "arr" : { "Name" : "Sam", "Salary" : 90000 }, "isMax" : true }
```